# Roughike bottom bar - position icon and label in landscape mode

Tags: java, android

it's possible change the position of icons and labels of bottombar in landscape mode ? In portrait have this position

# icon

---- label

i would like change position in landscape

icon # ---- label

Comment: create different layout file for portrait and landscape mode

Comment: but can't modify xml of roughike